# webpack:// folder not showing in devtools for SPFx project

Tags: webpack, google-chrome-devtools, spfx

I am working with the same SPFx 1.11 Projects for almost a year now.
Lately I can't debug anymore because, after running  `gulp serve --nobrowser` the webpack:// folder not showing in devtools.

I tried in many browsers and debugging with VS code. Nothing works.

Sometimes if I go back a version or 2, It starts showing the webpack:// folder and I can debug.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue.
I can't continue my work like this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be very simple.
I deleted the package from the sharepoint catalog then the browser had to load the local version of the code and showed the webpack:// folder

Hope it helps anyone.